# Get max value in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
var arr = [
    ["a","1"],
    ["b","3"],
    ["a","2"],
    ["b","5"]
]
```

I want to extract the max value in the above arrays.

My desired results:

```
  [
      ["a","2"],
      ["b","5"]
  ]
```

**UPDATE:**
I tried the following code:

```
var arr_res = [];
var number_max = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr_res.includes(arr[i][0]) == false){
        if(arr[i][1] > number_max){
            number_max = arr[i][1];
            arr_res.push([arr[i][0],number_max]);
        }
    }
}
```

The result is not as expected.

Any help much appreciated! Thanks very much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using [**Array.prototype.reduce()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) make an iteration over the array and form an Object to hold the max value. Since we have multiple `a`, `b` (and so many...), we used Object to make the key unique. In every iteration check if the key (`a, b, ....`) is exist or not in `old` (All previous iteration value). If exist then compare the current value to existing value and replace if necessary, add the current iteration value to `old` else.

Finally convert the Object to array using [**Object.entries()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

Example:

```js
const arr = [["292", "3"], ["277", "7"], ["280", "8"], ["281", "9"], ["277", "2"], ["280", "1"], ["281", "2"], ["292", "5"]];
const res = Object.entries(arr.reduce((old, cur) => {
    typeof old[cur[0]] === 'undefined' && (old[cur[0]] = +cur[1])
    if (Number(cur[1]) > old[cur[0]]) {
        old[cur[0]] = +cur[1]
    }
    return old
}, {}))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: It was wrong in this case: var arr = `[["292", "3"],
["277", "7"],
["280", "8"],
["281", "9"],
["277", "2"],
["280", "1"],
["281", "2"],
["292", "5"]]`
the result is: `[["277", 2],
["280", 1],
["281", 2],
["292", 5]]`

Comment: Updated the answer, Please now check it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic roadmap how you could solve your problem:

- create a variable to store the result arrays (e. g. `var result = [];`)
- iterate over the array's elements
- check the first element of each inner array

  - if its first element (the letter) does not have a record in `result`, add it
  - otherwise, check the second inner array element (the number)

    - if the number stored in result array is lower than the number of the current record, replace it by the current record's number

Useful JavaScript commands for your purpose are: [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried but did not produce the expected results, you can just help me code wrong somewhere

Comment: `includes` does not perform what you think it does. Because `arr_res` contains inner arrays and not plain values, `arr_res.includes(arr[i][0])` will always be false. You could try to use `find` instead to search for an inner array access.

Comment: I tried using `find` but not the result. Can you suggest code to help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use reduce and Math.max, it's a one liner basically

```js
const arr = [
  ["a","1"],
  ["b","3"],
  ["a","2"],
  ["b","5"],
];

const res = [...arr.reduce((a, [k, v]) => a.set(k, Math.max(a.get(k) || Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER, Number(v))), new Map)];
console.log(res);
```